# Why do countries like Pakistan, India, and Bangladesh have a parliamentary form of democracy?

Tags: india, pakistan

Why do countries like Pakistan, India, and Bangladesh have a parliamentary form of democracy?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These countries basically all use the [Westminster parliamentary system of government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westminster_system) which is modelled after the UK parliamentary system.

This parliamentary system is mainly used by former British Empire colonies upon gaining independence and Pakistan, India, and Bangladesh were all formerly ruled by the British. Both [India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_independence_movement) and [Pakistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pakistan_Movement) gained independence from Britain and [Bangladesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proclamation_of_Bangladeshi_Independence) then gained independence from Pakistan.

Since they did not reform their system of government, they are still using the Westminster system of governance till date and thus they do not have the presidential form of democracy.

Comment: What do you mean *"they did not reform their system"* - why do you think the Presidential form of governance is better than Parliamentary form of governance? (And note that neither India or Bangladesh blindly copied the British system - both are constitutional democracies, with an independent judiciary unlike the British).